# problem running react native on emulator and physical device on Windows

Tags: react-native

I followed all steps here https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup (React Native CLI QuickStart) but nothing helps every time I try to run the application I face this problem I think it because java jdk or the gradle (I did everything correct) can anybody help please

I followed all steps here https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup (React Native CLI QuickStart) but nothing helps every time I try to run the application I face this problem I think it because java jdk or the gradle (I did everything correct) can anybody help please

```html
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details      
File C:\Users\Mouhammad-PC\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Failed to download any source lists!
IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:515)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:513)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:512)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:553)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:292)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:395)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1205)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:247)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:624)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:547)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:61)      
        at com.android.repository.impl.downloader.LocalFileAwareDownloader.downloadAndStream(LocalFileAwareDownloader.java:51)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:149)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactproject@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactproject@0.0.1 android script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mouhammad-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-06T19_21_06_301Z-debug.log
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run android" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 28.0.3
```

Looks like you need to go into the Android Studio settings and make sure you have that specific version installed (there are many, and you can install multiple of them)